# Does passing a string from Rust to Python like this cause memory leaks?

Tags: python, rust, memory-leaks, ffi

I'm currently tinkering with interfacing between **Python and Rust** for a hobby. (Clearly I have too much time on my hands.) The problem I'm working on right now is passing **large integers** between the two languages.

Passing large integers from Python to Rust was suprisingly straighforward. You convert the large integer into an array of 32-bit integers, and Rust is commendably laid back about the whole thing. The problem is going the other way: passing a large integer from Rust to Python. Rust really doesn't like passing arrays to external interface!

A solution which I have found, which some may find hacky but which I find acceptable, is to convert the large integer into a **string**, and then pass that string to Python, which will then convert it back into an integer. That seems to function, but, on the basis of Vladimir Matveev's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30510764/returning-a-string-from-rust-function-to-python), I'm worried that I may be introducing memory leaks. Am I?

(Note that, if I try to call the `free` function that Vladimir Matveev recommends immediately after receiving the string from Rust, it gives me a `core dumped` fault.)

This is what my Rust code looks like:

```rust
const MAX_DIGITS: usize = 100;

unsafe fn import_bigint(digit_list: PortableDigitList) -> BigInt {
    let digits = Vec::from(*digit_list.array);
    let result = BigInt::new(Sign::Plus, digits);

    return result;
}

fn export_bigint(n: BigInt) -> *mut c_char {
    let result_str = n.to_str_radix(STANDARD_RADIX);
    let result = CString::new(result_str).unwrap().into_raw();

    return result;
}

#[repr(C)]
pub struct PortableDigitList {
    array: *const [u32; MAX_DIGITS]
}

#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern fn echo_big_integer(
    digit_list: PortableDigitList
) -> *mut c_char {
    let big_integer = import_bigint(digit_list);

    println!("Received big integer: {:?}. Sending it back...", big_integer);

    return export_bigint(big_integer);
}
```

---

Someone requested a MWE. Here it is. This is my `lib.rs`:

```rust
use std::ffi::CString;

use libc::c_char;

#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern fn return_string() -> *mut c_char {
    let result_string = "4294967296";

    println!("Returning string to Python: {}", result_string);

    let result = CString::new(result_string).unwrap().into_raw();

    return result;
}

#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern fn free_string(pointer: *mut c_char) {
    let _ = CString::from_raw(pointer);
}
```

And this is my Cargo.toml:

```ini
[package]
name = "return_string"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
name = "return_string"
crate-type = ["dylib"]

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
libc = "0.2.152"
```

Using `cargo build --release`, I then compile this into an .so file, which is what I call from Python, like so:

```py
from ctypes import CDLL, c_char_p, cast

lib = CDLL("return_string/target/release/libreturn_string.so")

rust_func = lib.return_string
rust_func.restype = c_char_p
result_pointer = rust_func()
result = cast(result_pointer, c_char_p).value.decode()
print("Rust returned string: "+result)

free_func = lib.free_string
free_func.argtypes = [c_char_p]
free_func(result_pointer)
```

If I run the above Python script, it gives me this output:

```
Returning string to Python: 4294967296
Rust returned string: 4294967296
munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: So: Have you considered just using the [PyO3](https://docs.rs/pyo3) crate, which makes all of this extremely easy, or you want the fun?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I definitely want a PINCH of fun, or, as you say, I would have resorted to a more off the shelf solution before now.

Comment: You are leaking the string, and the fix will be to create a `free_big_integer(*mut c_char)` function and calls it from Python when you're done with the string.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman As I said in the question, I've tried that, and it gives me a segmentation fault. I know that the big integer is going to be less than 2^3200. If I choose to represent it as a binary string, then it's going to be, at most, 3200 characters wide. Could that information help me out here at all?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), i.e. the full Rust and Python code that causes a segfault.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I'm not going to be able to do that right now, but I will do so over the next 24 hours.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Added MWE as requested. I apologise: it wasn't a segmentation fault; it was a core dumped error. (I was getting myself mixed up with another problem, which is now resolved.)

Comment: Note that the target needs to be `cdylib`, not `dylib`. This is not the issue, though.