# What is a correct way of getting and setting last error message through FFI?

Tags: rust, runtime-error, ffi, backtrace

I'm wrapping a C API (dylib) that exposes a setter and getter API for the last error message:

```
extern "C" {
    /// GetLastError is thread-safe
    pub fn GetLastError() -> *const ::std::os::raw::c_char;
    pub fn SetLastError(msg: *const ::std::os::raw::c_char);
}
```

The simplest way of wrapping them is as follows

```
use std::error::Error;
use std::ffi::CStr;
use std::fmt::{self, Display, Formatter};
use std::os::raw::c_char;

pub struct MyError;

impl MyError {
    pub fn get_last() -> &'static str {
        unsafe {
            match CStr::from_ptr(c_api::GetLastError()).to_str() {
                Ok(s) => s,
                Err(_) => "Invalid UTF-8 message",
            }
        }
    }

    pub fn set_last(msg: &'static str) {
        unsafe {
            c_api::SetLastError(msg.as_ptr() as *const c_char);
        }
    }
}

impl Display for MyError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", MyError::get_last())
    }
}

impl Error for MyError {
    fn description(&self) -> &'static str {
        MyError::get_last()
    }

    fn cause(&self) -> Option<&Error> {
        None
    }
}
```

This seems to work correctly getting the last error message. However, setting the last error message seems naive and it clutters previous messages in the stack frame!

For example;

```
let msg: &'static str = "invalid";
MyError::set_last(msg);
println!("Last error msg: {}", MyError::get_last());
```

outputs `Last error msg: invalidLast error msg`, or

```
assert_eq!(MyError::get_last().trim(), msg);
```

fails with

```
thread 'tests::set_error' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `"invalidassertion failed: `(left == right)`\n  left: ``,\n right: ``"`,
 right: `"invalid"`'
```

What's a correct way doing this?

I thought of using [backtrace](https://github.com/alexcrichton/backtrace-rs), but found little explanations in the crate and it led to nowhere!

Comment: See also [How do I convert a C string into a Rust string and back via FFI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24145823/how-do-i-convert-a-c-string-into-a-rust-string-and-back-via-ffi/24148033#24148033)

Comment: [The Rust FFI Omnibus](http://jakegoulding.com/rust-ffi-omnibus/)

Comment: Is the C API thread-safe? Is the lifetime of the errors really `'static` (ie, an error is valid until the end of the program)?

Comment: @MatthieuM, yes and yes!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rust strings are not 0-terminated, however, you assume they are when you do:

```
c_api::SetLastError(msg.as_ptr() as *const c_char);
```

Because C APIs detect the end of a string by the presence of a null byte.

A proper way to do this would be:

```
let c_string = CString::new("message").unwrap(); // will add a null byte
unsafe {
    c_api::SetLastError(c_string.as_ptr());
}
```

Depending on whether the C API makes a copy of the string or not, you might want to use `into_raw` plus proper deinitialization handling if necessary.